# Is there a way to "expect" instance of certain Java class in JavaScript code?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, casting

Assume that I have Foo.class in Java:

```
public class Foo {
    public int id;
    public String data;
}
```

And that I have Foo "class" in JavaScript:

```
function Foo(id, data) {
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
}
```

Also, assume that I have Java controller that returns instance of Foo.class as a response to a REST request. In my JavaScript (AngularJS) code the request is sent as:

```
$http.get(url + 'bar/get-foo/')
    .success(function (response) {
        var foo = new Foo(response.id, response.data);
        logger.info("SUCCESS: /get-foo");
    })
    .error(function (error_message) {
        logger.error(error_message)
    });
```

And it works. But is there a way to avoid passing every property from response to Foo constructor (some sort of expecting the Foo object, or casting it into a Foo object)?

I tried using `Object.create(Foo, response)` but I get `TypeError: Property description must be an object: true`

Of course there's always a possibility of refactoring the JavaScript side Foo constructor into:

```
function Foo(foo) {
    this.id = foo.id;
    this.data = foo.data;
}
```

But, that would require refactor of large portion of the codebase.

Thanks for your time. I appreciate it!

PS: For those who wonder why do I need this: It's not a problem with small classes like Foo, but some responses are instances of a much larger classes (with over a dozen of fields), which are not under my control.

**EDIT:** I accepted Chichozell's answer simply because it requires the least amount of work. Robin's and jonnyknowsbest's answers also work, (and will work for pure JavaScript, unlike Chichozell's answer, which is AngularJS specific). Haven't tried Laurentiu L.'s answer, but looks like it should also work.
Anyway this is A solution (not THE solution):

```
.success(function (response) {
    var foo = new Foo();
    angular.extend(foo, response); // angular.merge() for "deep-copy"
    //...
}
```

Big thanks to everyone who answered/commented/edited in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your Java thinking on javascript, try using angular.extend(), which will "copy" the properties of an object to another

```
this = angular.extend(this, response)
```

In the foo function, or directly on the controler:

```
 Foo = angular.extend(Foo, response)
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew about those AngularJS functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to "deserialise" the JSON you receive back as the response to an initialised object:

```
function JSONToObj(jsondata) {
    var json = JSON.parse(jsondata);

    var name = null;
    for(var i in json) { //Use first property as name
        name = i;
        break;
    }

    if (name == null)
        return null;

    var obj = new window[name]();
    for(var i in json[name])
        obj[i] = json[name][i];

    return obj;
}
```

This assumes that the constructor exists in the global scope and that the response is JSON-formatted as such:

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "id": "the id",
        "data": "the data"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're executing the first property as a global constructor...?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand! Perhaps to clarify your answer, provide an example of what the JSON-formatted response should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8t52Lj/1/) to achieve the structure you describe. The createObject function couold look something like the following code snippet.

```
function createObject(response, toCreate){
    var newObject = new toCreate();
    for(var attr in response){
        if(newObject.hasOwnProperty(attr)){
            newObject[attr] = response[attr];   
        }
    }
    return newObject;
}
```

Where you have createObject which takes a js object with the same attributes as your function as the response parameter, and a function (the object you want to create) as the toCreate parameter.

See the jsFiddle console log output, and you see that it works.

You could also, as seen in the jsFiddle, remove the check for hasOwnProperty to set the all attributes from the response regardless if the javascript function has them defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it pretty generic if you want to. And there wouldn't be too much refactoring to do, and this solution would ease your future changes to both classes.

You may change your Foo javascript object to an Angular JS service and inject it wherever you need it. This way you can have your data available globally. It's better than that local variable foo.

```
yourApp.factory('Foo',
        function () {
            //set a default or just initialize it
            var fooObject= {};
            return {
                getId: function () { return fooObject.id; },
                getData: function() { return fooObject.data;},
                setId: function(newId){fooObject.id = newId},
                setData: function(newData){fooObject.data=newData;},

                initializeFromObject : function(response){
                     for (var prop in response){
                          fooObject[prop] = response[prop];
                     }
                }
            };
        }
    );
```

You can also make the creation of new services safer with methods like hasAllProperties (by iterating through the object's properties, whether it is an array or object). ; hasNullValues and so on.

Hope this helps and you see it's value.